# Mark infopath field read-only after it been submitted

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, infopath

I have some infopath forms that have a drop down list control that is connected to a SharePoint list that pulls in all of our client names, the drop down list is called 'Client'

When the form is first created the user can obviously select a client, then they submit the form

Then when the form is opened again in the browser the 'Client' drop down field is read-only

How do I make the field read-only?
I am using InfoPath 2013 and SharePoint 2013 Enterprise

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a field in the data source which is hidden, once submitted change its value to True or anything you want. Then on the client dropdown list make a conditional formatting that if this field is True, then disable this control.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm fairly new to infopath, can you explain in steps with more detail

Thanks

Comment: On the right pane, right click on the root folder which is called MyFields, and click Add, call it IsSubmitted, and click ok, now you will have a field added to the data source (on the right pane) but not on the form, which is what we want, a hidden field. When you click submit, make a rule to change this field's value to Yes, just write the word "Yes". Then click on your dropdown, and from the ribbon in the rules category, choose manage rules, then add a formatting rule then choose the condition for this rule to execute when the IsSubbmitted = Yes, then Disable this control.